# How to write syntax to sum values for unique IDs in Survey123 Summary Report?

Tags: reports, syntax, arcgis-survey123, summary

How do I get a sum of values for a question for each uniquely named pump station in a Survey123 summary report?

I've developed a workflow for my client to do Pump Station inspections using Survey123.  They can do as many inspections per pump station as they want in a given month.  Each month they compile the inspection data in a monthly report (See screenshot below)
[image]

The report compiles the monthly inspection data for each pump station and provides a sum of the values collected for the specified date range (the date range is chosen when running the report in Survey123)

To recreate this report in Survey123 using the Survey123 inspection data, it seems I need to create a summary report. But I'm struggling with the syntax especially when there are multiple inspections for one pump station in a month.  Using online forums etc.  I was able to get the correct syntax to only show the unique pump station names, but I'm unsure what syntax I should be using to say, for example, "sum all the pump 1 run hours for each unique pump station name."

My working syntax is below.  Again, I was able to get the Pump Station name to show only the unique names and to not duplicate the names when there are more than one inspections done on a pump station.  But I can't figure out to sum each question for each pump station. In addition to that, I also only want to show the most recent inspection date for each pump station.

```
Pump Station Name:
${#PumpStationLogs | stats:"count,FACILITYID":"PSNAME": "" | where:"1=1" | orderByFields:"PSNAME ASC" }${PSNAME} ${/}

Last Inspection Date:
${#PumpStationLogs | stats:"count,FACILITYID":"PSNAME": "" | where:"1=1" | orderByFields:"PSNAME ASC" }${REPDATE | format:"MM/DD/YYYY"} ${/}

Sum of Pump 1 Run Hours:
${#PumpStationLogs} ${P1_RNHrs} ${/}
```